# GAE NDB: Adding and automatically occupying new fields

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

So let's say I have this model:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
```

After a week, a few hundred User entities are created. Now I want to add another field:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    username_lower = ndb.StringProperty() # username.lower()
```

I am not going to ask each user to input their the lowercase version of their existing  username, so how can I occupy these fields for each User entity myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make a script, to run once, that does this:

```
for user in User.query():
    user.username_lower = username.lower()
    user.put()
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer @IanGSY. This seems like the most obvious solution. I thought there might be a GAE convention to alter such a large amount of data, since if this method fails, then we might be risking a lot of data. Is there any precaution to take before this? Perhaps ether is an option to export datastore entities?

Answer (score 3):

Lowercase user name is actually the example used for Computed properties.

> Computed properties (**ComputedProperty**) are read-only properties whose
>   value is computed from other property values by an
>   application-supplied function. The computed value is written to the
>   Datastore so that it can be queried and displayed in the Datastore
>   viewer, but the stored value is ignored when the entity is read back
>   from the Datastore; rather, the value is recomputed by calling the
>   function whenever the value is requested. For example:

```
class SomeEntity(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  name_lower = ndb.ComputedProperty(lambda self: self.name.lower())

x = SomeEntity(name='Nick')

x.name = 'Nick'
assert x.name_lower == 'nick'
x.name = 'Nickie'
assert x.name_lower == 'nickie'
```

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties#computed

As you have no stored value for the early models it does not matter that it is not present, as it is not used directly anyway.